# Java RPC Service in Jar file

Tags: java, web-services, jar, soapui, rpc

Im getting an error whenever I run my Java jar. Basically the business logic that I have in Jar is calling some webservice. Im not sure on what to add when exporting to jar regarding on RPC service.

By the way to generate the jar, What I did in is just export the java project as jar.

Hoping you could help me to resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: please provide `... 7 more` error stack details to help viewers

Comment: Hi Thanks, I think I was able to fixed this. The solution that I did is, I exported my codes using Runnable jar instead export as jar only so that the the other jar dependencies are included in jar file.

Comment: provide this as an answer in case someone else gets into same issue